# Remove special character (?, ()) from value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, special-characters

I would like to have a code in order to remove special character such as `?` from values in a column in a dataframe.

I would like to remove from

```
()?()()() hello world'
```

the `()` and the `?`.

However, when I am using the following code:

```py
Community_final_level_2_description = Community_final_level_2_description.replace('()', ' ', regex=True)
```

or

```py
Community_final_level_2_description.replace('?', ' ', regex=True)
```

it is not working and I get an error.

Can someone provide me the proper code ?

Answer (score 2):

`(`/`)`/`?` are special characters for regex. Try to escape them:

```py
df["column"] = df["column"].replace(r"\?|\(\)", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         column
0   hello world
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
                  column
0  ()?()()() hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

If one has a dataframe `df` that looks like the following

```
                       A                      B
0  ()?()()() hello world  ()?()()() hello world
1  ()?()()() hello world  ()?()()() hello world
2  ()?()()() hello world  ()?()()() hello world
```

And one wants to remove the `()` and `?` from every column, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a custom lambda function as follows

```
df_new = df.apply(lambda x: [i.replace('()', '').replace('?', '') for i in x])

[Out]:

              A             B
0   hello world   hello world
1   hello world   hello world
2   hello world   hello world
```

---

**Notes:**

- There are strong opinions on using `.apply`, so one might want to check this: [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869)